# SIM 1 Card Full notification on HTC Desire SV

Tags: sms, sim-card

On my **HTC** Desire **SV**, a notification says

> SIM card is full Delete some messages to make more space.

I've deleted all my messages and it still won't go away. I've clicked on it and it leads me to a page that says

> no messages on the SIM card:

under the title that says

> SMS messages on SIM card.

so, I guess my real question is how do I get rid of this? how do I access the SIM card to where I can delete photos and/or messages off of it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with your phone, that it only shows the SMS on your phone, not with the SIM card. If you go into your SMS application and check  settings, you should have an option which says something like: "Manage SIM SMS". From there, you should be able to delete the SMS from your SIM card.

Another option is to insert your SIM card in an another phone (probably an older phone will have access to your SIM's SMS) and try it from there.

Yet another option is to try some SMS management application like [GoSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) which may enable you to erase SMS from the SIM card, though I haven't tried such applications, as it's been a long time since I used SMS.

Comment: I tried your first option and there is not a single SMS in SIM memory. I checked this SIM card in other mobile phone. I think the problem is some thing else.

Comment: You got me lost here then. Usually the message is because there are some SMS in the SIM, not on the phone. I recall reading some time ago that the message could also be for having the agenda full. Do you store your contacts on the SIM or on the phone, linked with Google account?

Comment: When you checked the SIM in another mobile, does it gives you the same warning message? If no, then this is a problem of your phone/ROM. What Android version do you have? I was googling a bit, and found some russian forum, where you could check (it's risky, be aware) to update your firmware: [forum](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=429766&st=2180#entry21545916)

Comment: I am storing all my contacts into SIM card and the phone is also linked with google account.
I was inserted the SIM card in low end Nokia mobile phone and nothing is there in "Inbox", "Sent items" and in "Draft".

Comment: @ AitorTheRed ...the link which you provided here ...is not readable by me...because in russian language...

Comment: @VinitVikash I don't speak russian. I used some translation tool, like translate.google.com. Yiou can trywith this [link](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=es&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2F4pda.ru%2Fforum%2Findex.php%3Fshowtopic%3D429766%26st%3D2180). Also, maybe the problem is for storing the contacts in the SIM card. You should move the contacts to the phone (and link the contacts to the google account).

Answer (score 0):

Go into Messaging, SMS Messages, Settings and change SMS storage location to Phone. This is on a Doogee phone, running Android 5.0-R25-2015_10_20.

Answer (score -5):

- Switch off your mobile
- Remove your mobile battery and SIM card
- Press your power button for 10 seconds
- Replace your battery and SIM card
- Switch on your mobile
- Issue cleared
- It worked for me :)